# For-In Loops multiple conditions

Tags: swift, xcode7.3, swift3

With the new update to Xcode 7.3, a lot of issues appeared related with the new version of Swift 3. One of them says "C-style for statement is deprecated and will be removed in a future version of Swift" (this appears in traditional `for` statements).

One of this loops has more than one condition:

```
for i = 0; i < 5 && i < products.count; i += 1 {

}
```

My question is, is there any elegant way (not use `break`) to include this double condition in a for-in loop of Swift:

```
for i in 0 ..< 5 {

}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It would be just as you're saying if you described it out loud:

```
for i in 0 ..< min(5, products.count) { ... }
```

That said, I suspect you *really* mean:

```
for product in products.prefix(5) { ... }
```

which is less error-prone than anything that requires subscripting.

It's possible you actually need an integer index (though this is rare), in which case you mean:

```
for (index, product) in products.enumerate().prefix(5) { ... }
```

Or you could even get a real index if you wanted with:

```
for (index, product) in zip(products.indices, products).prefix(5) { ... }
```

Comment: Your answer demonstrates perfectly why Apple is removing the C-style `for` statement: because there are other, way more Swifty ways to accomplish the same thing, and often people only use the old style `for` statement to iterate an array anyway.

Comment: Very complete answer! Thanks! with the two first was enough for me. About the two last answer (which both have compile errors): in the third answer, enumerate is a method and in the fourth answer "Value of type Range<DctionaryIndex<String, String>> has no member zip", so this method seems that doesn't exist for this type. Thanks you very much!

Comment: Fixed the syntax. Thanks for noting it.

Answer (score 21):

You can use `&&` operator with `where` condition like

```
let arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

for i in 1...arr.count where i < 5  {
    print(i)
}
//output:- 1 2 3 4

for i in 1...100 where i > 40 && i < 50 && (i % 2 == 0) {
     print(i)
}
//output:- 42 44 46 48
```

Comment: Is it possible to add optional binding after the where?

Comment: @ScottyBlades I don't think so we can use `let` statement here, however, we can use `!= nil` here or If you are trying to check class type then  you  can use `is` as well like `object is UIButton`

Answer (score 6):

Another way to do so would be like this

```
for i in 0 ..< 5 where i < products.count {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One more example. Loop through all UILabel in subviews:

```
for label in view.subviews where label is UILabel {
    print(label.text)
}
```

**UPDATE**

Now the `subview` inside the loop is `UIView` and needs to additionally case it to `UILabel`

```
for subview in view.subviews where subview is UILabel {
    let label = subview as? UILabel
    print("\(label?.text ?? "")")
}
```

Comment: In the current implementation of Swift this doesn't work, because label isn't cast to UILabel, even though it is known to be a UILabel. It would be a good feature but it isn't implemented yet.

Comment: @ThomasW thank you to point it out! I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here’s a simple solution:

```
var x = 0
while (x < foo.length && x < bar.length) {

  // Loop body goes here

  x += 1
}
```